# What does "to the exclusion of all others" entail for partner migration to Australia?

Tags: immigration, australia, marriage

My partners and I are [polyamorous](https://www.morethantwo.com/polyamory.html): we all have multiple serious dating relationships, with the knowledge and approval of all parties. One of my partners is an Australian citizen living in the state of Victoria. All of her partners are foreigners living overseas. Currently, no one is married to anyone or in any relationship that would be recognised as de facto under Victorian law.

My partner's fiance wants to move to Australia and marry my partner. He's planning to apply for a [prospective marriage visa](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/300-), followed by a partner visa once they are married.

The partner migration booklet lists "a mutual commitment to a shared life as husband and wife **to the exclusion of all others**" as a visa requirement for married couples. (For de facto couples it's "a mutual commitment to a shared life to the exclusion of all others".)

What is needed to meet this requirement?

Of course they can't marry any other people, but that's already in marriage law. Do my partner and I have to break up, or would lesser restrictions (e.g. remaining long-distance, not sharing money, not going out as a couple) be enough?

Conversely, if we break up, we would like to stay friends, which implies calling each other often and visiting each other. It seems difficult to prove that the calls and visits are purely friendly and we are not simply hiding a continuing relationship. Would these actions make it impossible for my partner and her fiance to prove that they are now exclusive?

Is there any way to find a migration agent with experience on this problem?

Comment: generally marriage is between only two persons in a lot of jurisdictions around the world. This means if you get married you will only be married to each other and not have second marriages (unless you divorce first). What you do outside of marriage should be no ones concern

Comment: On the other hand it might be difficult to prove that the marriage is valid and not done only to get an easier route to the visa (marriage of convenience), especially if they realize you don't really believe in two-party marriages

Comment: @SztupY I have edited the question to make it clearer only two people will be *married* and other relationships aren't marriages or legally recognised de facto. Feel free to suggest edits if it's still unclear.

Comment: I would read that as "to the exclusion of all other [husbands or wives]", but I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: I was just saying that this "to the exclusion of all others" is just the generic marriage provision (e.g. you have to accept this if you want to get married). From a visa perspective I believe if they figure out that you also have other partners they might believe the marriage is only of convenience, which is usually a big no for partner visas